# Boolean modifier "conflicts" with Bevel modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bevel

im new here and i have just a question:Im using blender from not a long time (excuse my bad english too),and while i was modelling a PS2 model,i encountered a problem.

I have a Bevel modifier on the upper part(not applied,just there)and it does his work,but as soon as i try to add a Boolean modifier to cut a hole(the P1 controller port) they just act as if they "conflict": I mean,if one is on,the other one doesnt work.Switching them up and down on the modifiers tab shows that only the first one actually takes effect on the mesh.

I tried even applying Bevel first,then cut the Boolean hole but if i do so the hole just doesnt happen.If i apply the Boolean difference,then the Bevel modifier just doesnt work in any way,even deleting and putting a new one.

I will try to upload some screenshot of the part that im talking about.I hope was not a stupid question,but i really cant figure out if i have to find another way or maybe im missing something.If needed i can try upload the file aswell.Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes please share the file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/   but sometimes you can't find a solution with modifiers and you need to do it manually

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6306" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6306/)     i hope the link is ok,first time trying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if you decrease the boolean object's *Subdivision Surface* subdivisions down to 2, it works, I can't tell you why though:

[image]